# Where to put environment variables for a SPA during docker build time in a CI pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

At build time in `localhost`, the environment variables are set in `.env` files.
At build time during a Continuos Integration process are set onto the `Dockerfile` using `ARG` and `ENV` so the CI is responsible of "hydrating" the values as build argument for docker build command.

I'm wondering if this is an scalable solution when the docker image needs a **considerable amount of environment variables** making the CI command line a bit cumbersome. Keeping in mind that is for a SPA and not sensible information or secret is been added as environment variable.
`

```
# This is an example of a dummy Dockerfile with multi stage
FROM your.npmregistry.com/node:16-alpine3.11 AS nginx_conf
LABEL owner=whoever
WORKDIR /build
COPY . .

FROM your.npmregistry.com/node:16-alpine3.11 AS build

LABEL owner=whoever
RUN apk --no-cache add python build-base
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

ARG THEME
ARG NEW_RELIC_ENABLED="true"

ENV REACT_APP_THEME=$THEME
ENV REACT_APP_NEW_RELIC_ENABLED=$NEW_RELIC_ENABLED

RUN yarn --frozen-lockfile && yarn build

FROM your.npmregistry.com/nginx:stable-alpine AS dist

LABEL owner=whoever
RUN this and that
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./foo.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./foo.sh"]
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "pid /tmp/nginx.pid; daemon off;"]

# This is just an example 
EXPOSE XYZ XYZ
```

`

An example of Jenkinsfile with just 2 arguments looks like this one below.

```
agent {
  dockerfile {
    filename 'docker/Dockerfile.nonprod'
    additionalBuildArgs "--target build --build-arg THEME=foo --build-arg NEW_RELIC_ENABLED=false -t foo-build"
    reuseNode true
  }
}
```

However if it requires a considerable amount of environment variables it could become cumbersome.
Just a dummy example below.

```
agent {
  dockerfile {
    filename 'docker/Dockerfile.nonprod'
    additionalBuildArgs "--target build --build-arg THEME=foo --build-arg NEW_RELIC_ENABLED=false --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo --build-arg another0=foo -t foo-build"
    reuseNode true
  }
}
```

I expect to have a solution that makes the code more readable.

Comment: Modern approach is to have same docker image for all environments and control env variables via orchestrator on the environment itself - i.e. in the simplest case this could be docker compose.